# How to find out the certain page number is exists in the jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to know whether there is any method to find out the certain page number is exists in the jquery datatable

Comment: Check it **[here](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info())**

Comment: You want to know if pagination for a page is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(table).datatable().page.info().pages
```

Use this function:

```
function is_page_exists(table, pagenum) {
  return table.page.info().pages > pagenum;
}
```